# What are these part numbers?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Can someone help me figure out what both of these LEGO part numbers are?

The first two pictures are the same brick at different angles to show it's strange design, while the third picture is the second brick, which also needs part identification.

**1)** [image]

**2)**. [image]

**3)**. [image]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like:

1. *[Part #47458 - Brick, Modified 1 x 2 x 2/3 No Studs, Wing End](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=48937#T=C&C=11)*.

   [image]
2. *[Part #4081a - Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Light - (Thin) Ring.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081a&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip%20Light%20-%20Thin%20Ring&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C)*

   [image]

or

3. *[Part #4081b - Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Light - (**Thicc**) Ring.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip%20Light%20-%20Thick%20Ring&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C)* [image]

Comment: Why "thicc" instead of "thick", which is used to describe the part? There are no parts named "[thicc](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=thicc)" on Bricklink. I find quoting incorrect naming isn't the best idea.

Comment: Thicc is a meme that the youngin's are doing these days.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer one part has two similar versions. Picture 3 shows the older [4081a](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081a#T=C) and not the newer [4081b](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b). This might be important, depending on your application. While both parts look to be very similar they have different properties. Older part has narrow/thin ring, which allows you to attach plates vertically on each side of the ring and such assembly won't be wider than the horizontal plate. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with newer part as ring is wider/ticker.